# Jira REST API doesn't have "ticket deleted" info --- so how to measure this?

Tags: api, jira

When an issue is deleted in Jira, there is no notification in any kind of incremental Jira API.

So for something simple like "Full Lead Time" or "Full Solve Time" -- those metrics can be mucked up because a "deleted ticket" will be "open" until the Sun burns out -- AND there's no way of knowing it's deleted. It just goes "poof".

Is there an efficient work around for this? My thoughts so far.

1. Direct Jira SQL access. Pull a full list of Issue IDs in Jira. Do an inner join/ filter against this list. The deleted tickets are tickets that are "gone" from the fully refreshed list.
2. Do a full cycle, 1000 issues at a time, of Issue IDs every night in Jira via the REST API. Basically the same as 1, but wildly inefficient for merely finding what tickets are deleted.
3. I vaguely heard of some kind of "delete listener" -- I'm unsure what that is. Would it work for every project? There may be some work-around where you can find "deleted work-flows" everyday and link those to deleted issues. Anyone know about this?

Obviously this is a massive flaw in the JIRA API that many other ticketing software (like Zendesk) actually gets right and puts a 'deleted' in the event and ticket meta-data. But is there a common sense way to work with the "delete problem" in Jira?

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid this situation by removing the option to delete issues to all users but administrators. Your users could dispose tickets by leaving them in a "Dissmised" status.

Comment: Right I did consider this. Would this be project to project, or instance wide, do you think? The setting that only admins can delete tickets?

Comment: It's up to you, you can have a different permission schemes for each project, but that is not the best aproach

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you might want to consider Jira webhooks which can notify you about deleted issues. If you receive the webhook, you can decide what you want to do with hit. For example, you can store them somewhere in a database or so.

Jira Server docs: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/webhooks/

Jira Cloud docs: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/webhooks/ You should consider that webhooks for Jira Cloud require a lot more work to implement, because you need to work with authentication and stuff like that. But since you mentioned to access the database directly, I assume you're using Jira Server.

Instead of implementing&hosting your own small app to receive webhooks, you might want to consider apps like [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) or [Automation for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215460/automation-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) which also should provide options to react to removed issues.